# How to use existing Firefox profile in Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I need to use an existing Firefox profile in Selenium using C#.
That profile has a configured add-on that i need.

I found some code googling but those were for Java, I tried the following code but it still doesn't work.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\software\\Files");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer on the official docs of selenium

```
var profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
FirefoxProfile profile = profileManager.GetProfile("Selenium");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Source: [Selenium docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#modifying-the-firefox-profile)

Answer (score 6):

In new versions works this method

**1) Go to firefox profile selection option**

[image]

**2) Create profile**

[image]

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfileManager().GetProfile("axixa");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.Profile = profile;
IWebDriver firefox = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass the profile object while instantiating the firefox driver. Like,

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

See [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/) for details.